# Installing DBI module and DBD::Oracle Driver Using CPANM

Tags: perl, solaris, cpan, dbi

So based on instructions I was given on stackoverflow, I was attempting to install a new version of Perl on my 64 bit Solaris virtual machine using perlbrew, in order to ultimately install 'cpanm' and install the CGI and DBI modules, as well as the DBD::Oracle driver. These are the steps I was following:

1) Install gcc and other build tools.

2,3) Install perlbrew...

4) Install the new Perl

Perl 5.16.0 was successfully installed after ignoring a test failure in Socket.pm

```
    Test Summary Report
    -------------------
    ../cpan/Socket/t/getnameinfo.t   (Wstat: 256 Tests: 14 Failed: 1)
      Failed test:  10
      Non-zero exit status: 1
```

5) Install the modules...

When I go to try and install the DBI module using `cpanm -v DBI`, this is the given output.

```
Test Summary Report
    -------------------
    t/zvg_85gofer.t               (Wstat: 256 Tests: 211 Failed: 1)
      Failed test:  107
      Non-zero exit status: 1
    t/zvn_85gofer.t               (Wstat: 256 Tests: 211 Failed: 1)
      Failed test:  81
      Non-zero exit status: 1
    t/zvp_85gofer.t               (Wstat: 256 Tests: 219 Failed: 1)
      Failed test:  89
      Non-zero exit status: 1
    Files=182, Tests=8252, 128 wallclock secs ( 3.67 usr  2.56 sys + 82.68 cusr 37.78 csys = 126.69 CPU)
    Result: FAIL
    Failed 3/182 test programs. 3/8252 subtests failed.
    *** Error code 255
    make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `test_dynamic'
    FAIL
    ! Installing DBI failed. See /home/oracle/.cpanm/build.log for details.
```

So I went ahead and did a `vi /home/oracle/.cpanm/build.log`, and this was what was in the build.log:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.5011 on perl 5.016000 built for i86pc-solaris
Work directory is /home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339087258.18143
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have /usr/bin/wget
You have /usr/sbin/tar, /usr/bin/gzip and /usr/bin/bzip2
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching DBI on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on DBI
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TI/TIMB/DBI-1.622.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking DBI-1.622.tar.gz
Entering DBI-1.622
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.63_02)
Configuring DBI-1.622
Running Makefile.PL
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.48 ... Yes (6.63_02)
Checking if you have Test::Simple 0.90 ... Yes (0.98)
Building and testing DBI-1.622
-> FAIL Installing DBI failed. See /home/oracle/.cpanm/build.log for details.
~
"~/.cpanm/build.log" 22 lines, 858 characters
```

**Output From Doing** `cd ~/.cpanm/latest-build/DBI-1.622` followed by `make test > /home/oracle/Desktop/DBI_Output` :

```
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/01basics.t .................... ok
t/02dbidrv.t .................... ok
t/03handle.t .................... ok
t/04mods.t ...................... ok
t/05concathash.t ................ ok
t/06attrs.t ..................... ok
t/07kids.t ...................... ok
t/08keeperr.t ................... ok
t/09trace.t ..................... ok
t/10examp.t ..................... ok
t/11fetch.t ..................... ok
t/12quote.t ..................... ok
t/13taint.t ..................... ok
t/14utf8.t ...................... ok
t/15array.t ..................... ok
t/16destroy.t ................... ok
t/19fhtrace.t ................... ok
t/20meta.t ...................... ok
t/30subclass.t .................. ok
t/31methcache.t ................. ok
t/35thrclone.t .................. skipped: this solaris perl 5.016000 not supported for DBI iThreads
t/40profile.t ................... ok
t/41prof_dump.t ................. ok
t/42prof_data.t ................. ok
t/43prof_env.t .................. ok
t/48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ......... ok
t/49dbd_file.t .................. ok
t/50dbm_simple.t ................ ok
t/51dbm_file.t .................. ok
t/52dbm_complex.t ............... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/60preparse.t .................. ok
t/65transact.t .................. ok
t/70callbacks.t ................. ok
t/72childhandles.t .............. ok
t/80proxy.t ..................... skipped: modules required for proxy are probably not installed (e.g., RPC/PlClient.pm)
t/85gofer.t ..................... ok
t/86gofer_fail.t ................ ok
t/87gofer_cache.t ............... ok
t/90sql_type_cast.t ............. ok
t/pod-coverage.t ................ skipped: Test::Pod::Coverage 1.04 required for testing POD coverage
t/pod.t ......................... skipped: Test::Pod 1.00 required for testing POD
t/zvg_01basics.t ................ ok
t/zvg_02dbidrv.t ................ ok
t/zvg_03handle.t ................ ok
t/zvg_04mods.t .................. ok
t/zvg_05concathash.t ............ ok
t/zvg_06attrs.t ................. ok
t/zvg_07kids.t .................. ok
t/zvg_08keeperr.t ............... ok
t/zvg_09trace.t ................. ok
t/zvg_10examp.t ................. ok
t/zvg_11fetch.t ................. ok
t/zvg_12quote.t ................. ok
t/zvg_13taint.t ................. skipped: Taint attribute tests not functional with DBI_AUTOPROXY
t/zvg_14utf8.t .................. ok
t/zvg_15array.t ................. ok
t/zvg_16destroy.t ............... ok
t/zvg_19fhtrace.t ............... ok
t/zvg_20meta.t .................. ok
t/zvg_30subclass.t .............. ok
t/zvg_31methcache.t ............. ok
t/zvg_35thrclone.t .............. skipped: this solaris perl 5.016000 not supported for DBI iThreads
t/zvg_40profile.t ............... ok
t/zvg_41prof_dump.t ............. ok
t/zvg_42prof_data.t ............. ok
t/zvg_43prof_env.t .............. ok
t/zvg_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ..... ok
t/zvg_49dbd_file.t .............. ok
t/zvg_50dbm_simple.t ............ ok
t/zvg_51dbm_file.t .............. ok
t/zvg_52dbm_complex.t ........... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvg_60preparse.t .............. ok
t/zvg_65transact.t .............. skipped: Transactions not supported by DBD::Gofer
t/zvg_70callbacks.t ............. ok
t/zvg_72childhandles.t .......... ok
t/zvg_80proxy.t ................. skipped: modules required for proxy are probably not installed (e.g., RPC/PlClient.pm)
t/zvg_85gofer.t ................. ok
t/zvg_86gofer_fail.t ............ skipped: Gofer DBI_AUTOPROXY
t/zvg_87gofer_cache.t ........... skipped: Gofer DBI_AUTOPROXY
t/zvg_90sql_type_cast.t ......... ok
t/zvn_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ..... ok
t/zvn_49dbd_file.t .............. ok
t/zvn_50dbm_simple.t ............ ok
t/zvn_51dbm_file.t .............. ok
t/zvn_52dbm_complex.t ........... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvn_85gofer.t ................. 
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/219 subtests 
    (less 16 skipped subtests: 202 okay)
t/zvp_01basics.t ................ ok
t/zvp_02dbidrv.t ................ ok
t/zvp_03handle.t ................ ok
t/zvp_04mods.t .................. ok
t/zvp_05concathash.t ............ ok
t/zvp_06attrs.t ................. ok
t/zvp_07kids.t .................. skipped: $h->{Kids} attribute not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_08keeperr.t ............... ok
t/zvp_09trace.t ................. ok
t/zvp_10examp.t ................. ok
t/zvp_11fetch.t ................. ok
t/zvp_12quote.t ................. ok
t/zvp_13taint.t ................. skipped: Taint attributes not supported with DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_14utf8.t .................. ok
t/zvp_15array.t ................. ok
t/zvp_16destroy.t ............... ok
t/zvp_19fhtrace.t ............... ok
t/zvp_20meta.t .................. ok
t/zvp_30subclass.t .............. ok
t/zvp_31methcache.t ............. ok
t/zvp_35thrclone.t .............. skipped: this solaris perl 5.016000 not supported for DBI iThreads
t/zvp_40profile.t ............... skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_41prof_dump.t ............. skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_42prof_data.t ............. skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_43prof_env.t .............. skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ..... ok
t/zvp_49dbd_file.t .............. ok
t/zvp_50dbm_simple.t ............ ok
t/zvp_51dbm_file.t .............. ok
t/zvp_52dbm_complex.t ........... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvp_60preparse.t .............. skipped: preparse not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_65transact.t .............. ok
t/zvp_70callbacks.t ............. skipped: $h->{Callbacks} attribute not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvp_72childhandles.t .......... ok
t/zvp_80proxy.t ................. skipped: modules required for proxy are probably not installed (e.g., RPC/PlClient.pm)
t/zvp_85gofer.t ................. ok
t/zvp_86gofer_fail.t ............ skipped: requires Callbacks which are not supported with PurePerl
t/zvp_87gofer_cache.t ........... ok
t/zvp_90sql_type_cast.t ......... ok
t/zvxgn_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ... ok
t/zvxgn_49dbd_file.t ............ ok
t/zvxgn_50dbm_simple.t .......... ok
t/zvxgn_51dbm_file.t ............ ok
t/zvxgn_52dbm_complex.t ......... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvxgn_85gofer.t ............... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/202 subtests 
    (less 35 skipped subtests: 165 okay)
t/zvxgnp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t .. ok
t/zvxgnp_49dbd_file.t ........... ok
t/zvxgnp_50dbm_simple.t ......... ok
t/zvxgnp_51dbm_file.t ........... ok
t/zvxgnp_52dbm_complex.t ........ skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvxgnp_85gofer.t .............. 
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/216 subtests 
    (less 40 skipped subtests: 175 okay)
t/zvxgp_01basics.t .............. ok
t/zvxgp_02dbidrv.t .............. ok
t/zvxgp_03handle.t .............. ok
t/zvxgp_04mods.t ................ ok
t/zvxgp_05concathash.t .......... ok
t/zvxgp_06attrs.t ............... ok
t/zvxgp_07kids.t ................ skipped: $h->{Kids} attribute not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_08keeperr.t ............. ok
t/zvxgp_09trace.t ............... ok
t/zvxgp_10examp.t ............... ok
t/zvxgp_11fetch.t ............... ok
t/zvxgp_12quote.t ............... ok
t/zvxgp_13taint.t ............... skipped: Taint attributes not supported with DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_14utf8.t ................ ok
t/zvxgp_15array.t ............... ok
t/zvxgp_16destroy.t ............. ok
t/zvxgp_19fhtrace.t ............. ok
t/zvxgp_20meta.t ................ ok
t/zvxgp_30subclass.t ............ ok
t/zvxgp_31methcache.t ........... ok
t/zvxgp_35thrclone.t ............ skipped: this solaris perl 5.016000 not supported for DBI iThreads
t/zvxgp_40profile.t ............. skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_41prof_dump.t ........... skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_42prof_data.t ........... skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_43prof_env.t ............ skipped: profiling not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ... ok
t/zvxgp_49dbd_file.t ............ ok
t/zvxgp_50dbm_simple.t .......... ok
t/zvxgp_51dbm_file.t ............ ok
t/zvxgp_52dbm_complex.t ......... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvxgp_60preparse.t ............ skipped: preparse not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_65transact.t ............ skipped: Transactions not supported by DBD::Gofer
t/zvxgp_70callbacks.t ........... skipped: $h->{Callbacks} attribute not supported for DBI::PurePerl
t/zvxgp_72childhandles.t ........ ok
t/zvxgp_80proxy.t ............... skipped: modules required for proxy are probably not installed (e.g., RPC/PlClient.pm)
t/zvxgp_85gofer.t ............... 
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/217 subtests 
    (less 40 skipped subtests: 176 okay)
t/zvxgp_86gofer_fail.t .......... skipped: requires Callbacks which are not supported with PurePerl
t/zvxgp_87gofer_cache.t ......... skipped: Gofer DBI_AUTOPROXY
t/zvxgp_90sql_type_cast.t ....... ok
t/zvxnp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t ... ok
t/zvxnp_49dbd_file.t ............ ok
t/zvxnp_50dbm_simple.t .......... ok
t/zvxnp_51dbm_file.t ............ ok
t/zvxnp_52dbm_complex.t ......... skipped: DBI::SQL::Nano is being used
t/zvxnp_85gofer.t ............... ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/zvn_85gofer.t               (Wstat: 256 Tests: 219 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  141
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/zvxgn_85gofer.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 202 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  87, 98
  Non-zero exit status: 2
t/zvxgnp_85gofer.t            (Wstat: 256 Tests: 216 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  138
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/zvxgp_85gofer.t             (Wstat: 256 Tests: 217 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  113
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=182, Tests=8231, 126 wallclock secs ( 3.41 usr  2.41 sys + 80.87 cusr 37.61 csys = 124.30 CPU)
Result: FAIL
*** Error code 255
```

**I then went ahead and tried to find out what was going wrong with zvxgn_85gofer.t. So I did the `make test TEST_VERBOSE=1`:**

```
t/zvxnp_85gofer.t ............... 
# Transports: null pipeone stream stream_ssh
# Policies: pedantic classic rush
# Count: 0
# =============
# Testing null transport with pedantic policy
#  dbi:Gofer:transport=null;policy=pedantic;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 1 - should connect to dbi:Gofer:transport=null;policy=pedantic;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 2
ok 3
ok 4
ok 5 - should detect prepare failure
ok 6
ok 7
ok 8
ok 9
ok 10
ok 11
ok 12 - go_response executed flag should be true
ok 13
ok 14
ok 15
ok 16
# Testing go_request_count and caching of simple values
ok 17
ok 18
ok 19
# use_remote=1 (policy=pedantic, transport=null) HASH(0x8a56738)
ok 20
ok 21
ok 22
ok 23 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 24 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 25
ok 26
# =============
# Testing null transport with classic policy
#  dbi:Gofer:transport=null;policy=classic;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 27 - should connect to dbi:Gofer:transport=null;policy=classic;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 28
ok 29
ok 30
ok 31 - The object isa DBI::st
ok 32
ok 33
ok 34
ok 35
ok 36
ok 37
ok 38 - go_response executed flag should be true
ok 39
ok 40
ok 41
ok 42
# Testing go_request_count and caching of simple values
ok 43
ok 44
ok 45
# use_remote=0 (policy=classic, transport=null) HASH(0x8a40118)
ok 46
ok 47
ok 48
ok 49 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 50 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 51
ok 52
# =============
# Testing null transport with rush policy
#  dbi:Gofer:transport=null;policy=rush;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 53 - should connect to dbi:Gofer:transport=null;policy=rush;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 54
ok 55
ok 56
ok 57 - The object isa DBI::st
ok 58
ok 59
ok 60
ok 61
ok 62
ok 63
ok 64 - go_response executed flag should be true
ok 65
ok 66
ok 67
ok 68
# Testing go_request_count and caching of simple values
ok 69
ok 70
ok 71
# use_remote=0 (policy=rush, transport=null) HASH(0x8a51920)
ok 72
ok 73
ok 74
ok 75 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 76 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 77
ok 78
# =============
# Testing pipeone transport with pedantic policy
#  dbi:Gofer:transport=pipeone;policy=pedantic;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 79 - should connect to dbi:Gofer:transport=pipeone;policy=pedantic;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 80
ok 81
ok 82
ok 83 - should detect prepare failure
ok 84
ok 85
ok 86
ok 87
ok 88
ok 89
ok 90 - go_response executed flag should be true
ok 91
ok 92
ok 93
ok 94
# Testing go_request_count and caching of simple values
ok 95
ok 96
ok 97
# use_remote=1 (policy=pedantic, transport=pipeone) HASH(0x8aa2600)
ok 98
ok 99
ok 100
ok 101 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 102 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 103
ok 104
# =============
# Testing pipeone transport with classic policy
#  dbi:Gofer:transport=pipeone;policy=classic;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 105 - should connect to dbi:Gofer:transport=pipeone;policy=classic;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 106
ok 107
ok 108
ok 109 - The object isa DBI::st
ok 110
ok 111
ok 112
ok 113
ok 114
ok 115
ok 116 - go_response executed flag should be true
ok 117
ok 118
ok 119
ok 120
# Testing go_request_count and caching of simple values
ok 121
ok 122
ok 123
# use_remote=0 (policy=classic, transport=pipeone) HASH(0x8aa2550)
ok 124
ok 125
ok 126
ok 127 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 128 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 129
ok 130
# =============
# Testing pipeone transport with rush policy
#  dbi:Gofer:transport=pipeone;policy=rush;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 131 - should connect to dbi:Gofer:transport=pipeone;policy=rush;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 132
ok 133
ok 134
ok 135 - The object isa DBI::st
ok 136
ok 137
ok 138
ok 139
ok 140
ok 141
ok 142 - go_response executed flag should be true
ok 143
ok 144
ok 145
ok 146
# Testing go_request_count and caching of simple values
ok 147
ok 148
ok 149
# use_remote=0 (policy=rush, transport=pipeone) HASH(0x8aa2b90)
ok 150
ok 151
ok 152
ok 153 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 154 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 155
ok 156
# =============
# Testing stream transport with pedantic policy
#  dbi:Gofer:transport=stream;policy=pedantic;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 157 - should connect to dbi:Gofer:transport=stream;policy=pedantic;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 158
ok 159
ok 160
ok 161 - should detect prepare failure
ok 162
ok 163
ok 164
ok 165
ok 166
ok 167
ok 168 - go_response executed flag should be true
ok 169
ok 170
ok 171
ok 172
# Testing go_request_count and caching of simple values
ok 173
ok 174
ok 175
# use_remote=1 (policy=pedantic, transport=stream) HASH(0x8abb8a8)
ok 176
ok 177
ok 178
ok 179 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 180 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 181
ok 182
# =============
# Testing stream transport with classic policy
#  dbi:Gofer:transport=stream;policy=classic;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 183 - should connect to dbi:Gofer:transport=stream;policy=classic;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 184
ok 185
ok 186
ok 187 - The object isa DBI::st
ok 188
ok 189
ok 190
ok 191
ok 192
ok 193
ok 194 - go_response executed flag should be true
ok 195
ok 196
ok 197
ok 198
# Testing go_request_count and caching of simple values
ok 199
ok 200
ok 201
# use_remote=0 (policy=classic, transport=stream) HASH(0x8abbec8)
ok 202
ok 203
ok 204
ok 205 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 206 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 207
ok 208
# =============
# Testing stream transport with rush policy
#  dbi:Gofer:transport=stream;policy=rush;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 209 - should connect to dbi:Gofer:transport=stream;policy=rush;perl=/home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl  -Mblib=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/blib;timeout=240;dsn=DBI:DBM:f_dir=/home/oracle/.cpanm/work/1339090926.19497/DBI-1.622/test_output_23432;dbm_type=SDBM_File;f_lockfile=0
ok 210
ok 211
ok 212
ok 213 - The object isa DBI::st
ok 214
ok 215
ok 216
ok 217
ok 218
ok 219
ok 220 - go_response executed flag should be true
ok 221
ok 222
ok 223
ok 224
# Testing go_request_count and caching of simple values
ok 225
ok 226
ok 227
# use_remote=0 (policy=rush, transport=stream) HASH(0x8aa7a40)
ok 228
ok 229
ok 230
ok 231 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 232 # skip caching of metadata methods returning sth not yet implemented
ok 233
ok 234
1..234
ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/85gofer.t                   (Wstat: 256 Tests: 215 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  137
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/zvg_85gofer.t               (Wstat: 256 Tests: 214 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  84
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/zvn_85gofer.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 200 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  85, 122
  Non-zero exit status: 2
t/zvp_85gofer.t               (Wstat: 256 Tests: 217 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  87
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/zvxgnp_85gofer.t            (Wstat: 256 Tests: 219 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  115
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=182, Tests=8208, 127 wallclock secs ( 3.86 usr  3.02 sys + 79.30 cusr 37.83 csys = 124.01 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 5/182 test programs. 6/8208 subtests failed.
```

Comment: you need to view the build.log and the fail test cases.  Figure out which test fail and why they fail.  Fix the failure if possible and make test again on the DBI package.

Comment: @MichaelN That's the problem though, I looked in the build log and didn't seem to find anything. I'll put what was in the build log in the OP.

Comment: The verbose output should be in the build.log, but apparently something went wrong.  Try `cpanm --verbose DBI`.  That will give you the full information on screen.  You could also try [upgrading cpanm to the latest version](https://metacpan.org/release/App-cpanminus) and see if that fixes things.

Comment: go into .cpanm, is there a build/source directory where DBI-1.622 is locate/being compiled?  Go there and run 'make test' and redirect the output to a file that you can see the errors and read thru it.  But try schwern sugggestion of --verbose first and see if the build.log is more useful

Comment: @Schwern, I tried updating cpanm then doing the `cpanm --verbose DBI`, it didn't seem to allow me to see the entire thing on my screen nor did it update the build.log. However, I did notice that I did not include the summary report before, so I added that to the OP.

Comment: @MichaelN so I did an `ls ~/.cpanm` and found it contains a **build.log, latest-build,** and **work**. I then did `ls ~/.cpanm/latest-build and saw DBI-1.622. So I did `cd ~/.cpanm/latest-build/DBI-1.622` then ran `make test > /home/oracle/Desktop/DBI_Output`. I added that output to the OP.

Comment: do "make test TEST_VERBOSE=1" in the dbi directory again and post the section of the error for the fail test zvxgn_85gofer.t.  the test_verbose=1 will detail what in the test fail.  If its a transport timeout it may be possible to edit the test to increase the timeout and it'll fix the make test.

Comment: Alright, so I went ahead and entered that command. I added it to the OP.

Comment: You gives us the verbose output of `t/zvxnp_85gofer.t` (which has no errors). That's useless X_X

Comment: Isn't that what MichaelIN asked for? And in the OP, in the 2nd to last section of code, that is where the test failures are occurring, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, all the failing tests relate to DBD::Gopher. (In turn, it might have to do with the failure of `getnameinfo` you got installing Perl, but that's purely a hypothesis.) You could force DBI's installation if you don't plan on using that.

```
cpan -f -i DBI
```

Note that I normally strongly advocate against forcing the installation of modules (because it doesn't magically make a module work, and because it's done without understanding of the consequences).

Comment: That's the thing though, this is my first time using all of this stuff and I have no idea if we'd need the DBD::Gopher or not. Have you ever used it before?

Comment: `cpanm -v -f -i DBI` seems to have worked. It says `Successfully reinstalled DBI-1.622` followed closely by `1 distribution installed`. Hopefully we never have to make use of Gopher? lol Thank you so much everyone for your help!!! Truly appreciate it!!